# Play Android Games on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, games, ubuntu-for-android, android-emulator

is there any method to play Android games on Ubuntu 22.04? It would be nice if PlayStore can also be added to it. I can find `apk` from 3rd party if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio) ships with an emulator which can simulate Android phones and tablets (and more, like watches and TV). You can pick a build of Android to run in it, and install additional packages as apk or whatever. It can emulate x86 processor builds of Android, and (often slower) arm builds. This may be useful if the game or application you want to run is only available for one of the architectures.

While this is somewhat overkill (it's a full on developer suite) for what you need, it's likely the most reliable and supported way to do it.

Once installed, and up to date, use the "Device Manager" section of Android Studio to create a virtual device - a virtual phone or tablet. Select a version of Android to support (such as Android 12) and you will (eventually) get a bootable virtual Phone on your desktop.

It all takes a bit of a while to setup, and requires some significantly sized downloads, but it works, and results in a genuine Android user experience in a window on your desktop or laptop.

It doesn't have the play store but you can side load that from the gapps.zip you can find online.

Comment: Recent Android SDK has emulator images with Google Play Store installed. However, some games may detect if it's running on an emulator and stops working due to [its unique identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2799097/2821954).